# Issue sending value from one class to other in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, render

Here I have list of values in index.js as

```
1
2
3
     render() {
    const { id,heading,body,status,user} = this.props
  const {det} = this.state
  console.log(val);
    return (
      <a href='/details' style={{ color: 'green' }}  onClick={this.sendValue.bind(this)}>
          <div className="member" style={this.style}>
          <h1>{id}</h1>
          <h3>Reported by: {user}</h3>
          <h3>{heading}</h3>
          <h5>{body}</h5>
          <h5>The current status is: {status}</h5>
        </div></a>
      )
  }
```

here if I click that div tag mentioned I should be able to render to details page with the id value. I should be able to append the id value with other url mentioned in the details.js

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: Can you add some code to show us what you have tried? Then someone here can help you improve your code.

Comment: You can use react-router to navigate to a new page in a single page app and also pass the value as a props

Comment: Thank you for the response. Provided a part of code. Please provide some code how props can be passed through react-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should check this [page](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) which uses react-router to implement your scenario.

There can be `<Link to="/one">1</Link>` for your case and a defined, `<Route path="/one" component={One} />` where One is the component which will be rendered when the url is '/one'

You can append the page number in the url after defining in the router as
`<Route path="/one/:pageNumber" component={One} />`

And in the detailed page component you can read the value using the object

```
this.props.match.params.pageNumber
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, every time I click it should render to same page and I should be able to use the value in rendered page

Comment: You mean you dont have to change the url?

Comment: Url have to be like /details?1 if  I click link 1, /details?2 if I click 2.

Comment: In details page I have the eg url: www.abc.com/page/ , if I append this page number over there I should be able to display the contents of that url

Comment: Yes. You can append the page number over the url. And there are more easier way than using query parameters. Check the edited answer for this.

Comment: Thank you for the solution given. Please give me a detailed solution going through my code once again.